# Programming a custom Map class using an array

Tags: c++, arrays, class, dictionary, associative-array

I'm trying to program my own implementation of a map class using templates and and not using vectors, only an array.

I have two classes: Element which stores the Key and the data.

```
template <typename K, typename DT>
class Element
{
  public:
    K key;
    DT data;
};
```

And the Map class.

Private Variables:

```
template <typename K, typename DT>
class myMap 
{
   typedef Element<K, DT> myElement;

private:
  myElement  *elements;
  int size;
```

Constructor:

```
Template <typename K, typename DT>
myMap<K, DT>::myMap()
{
 //An initial map with a size of 10 potential elements.
 size = 10;
 elements = new myElement[size];    
}
```

Ok my question is; In my insert method, which adds a new element into the array I'm having problems accessing the elements data from within the array.

```
template <typename K, typename DT>
void myMap<K, DT>::insert(const K &key, const DT &val)
{
 /*A temporary element to store the data which is then stored
 in the array.*/
 myElement *temp = new myElement;
 temp->key = key;
 temp->data = val;

 elements[i]->key //This isn't allowed, It's not letting me access the key for the element at I

 delete temp;
}
```

I can get to it like this:

```
elements->key;
```

Basically I need to be able to access the array within the class and access the data from the element class so that I can check if the key is already present to avoid duplication.

Comment: Why are you using an array for a map implementation? Sounds like you're implementing `std::vector` instead of a map.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious maybe he's learning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `elements[i].key`

The elements array is a pointer, but when you array index it, you just get a regular old myElement object.

Usually the compiler's error message is pretty clear on this.  I'd go back and reread the error you got.

Comment: . operator doesn't seem to work either and there is no error message. Could it be how the array is declared?

Comment: No.  It's probably another unrelated error.  Here is some working code using the . operator: http://www.codeshare.io/OLwiW

Comment: Thank you, I think the problem was more to do with Visual Studio Intellisense, it's not showing the code completion for the array but it compiles and seems to work OK. If that made sense.